# rsync : copy files if local file doesn't exist. Don't check filesize, time, checksum etc

Tags: cygwin, rsync

I am using rsync to backup a million images from my linux server to my computer (windows 7 using Cygwin).

The command I am using now is :

```
rsync -rt --quiet --rsh='ssh -p2200' root@X.X.X.X:/home/XXX/public_html/XXX /cygdrive/images
```

Whenever the process is interrupted, and I start it again, it takes long time to start the copying process.
I think it is checking each file if there is any update.

The images on my server won't change once they are created.

So, is there any faster way to run the command so that it may copy files if local file doesn't exist without checking filesize, time, checksum etc...

Please suggest.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

did you try this flag -- it might help, but it might still take some time to resume the transfer:

```
       --ignore-existing
          This tells rsync to skip updating files that already exist on the destination  (this  does  not  ignore
          existing directories, or nothing would get done).  See also --existing.

          This  option  is  a  transfer  rule,  not  an exclude, so it doesn't affect the data that goes into the
          file-lists, and thus it doesn't affect deletions.  It just limits the files that the receiver  requests
          to be transferred.

          This  option  can be useful for those doing backups using the --link-dest option when they need to con-
          tinue a backup run that got interrupted.  Since a --link-dest run is copied into a new directory  hier-
          archy  (when  it  is used properly), using --ignore existing will ensure that the already-handled files
          don't get tweaked (which avoids a change in permissions on the hard-linked files).  This does mean that
          this option is only looking at the existing files in the destination hierarchy itself.
```